# What's an efficient way to select an element by accessibility label in selenium-webdriver and appium?

Tags: node.js, selenium, react-native, appium

I've just started auto end-to-end testing with my react native app, both ios and android, context is nodejs. Client is `selenium-webdriver`, which connects to `appium` server.

According to several sources, the best way to locate an element in React Native is to supply an `accessibilityLabel` to a `View`. However, in `selenium-webdriver`, there's no such function like:

`driver.find_elements_by_accessibility_id('some id')`

Currently I'm using a workaround instead:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@accessibilityLabel="some label"]'))`

As it traverses all attributes of all elements, not hard to imagine its low efficiency. What could be a better approach?

**P.S.** I chose `selenweb driveriver` as client because it's also used for testing our web app, so I don't need to go through another learning curve. But if needed, I'm happy to switch to another client.

Comment: In Python I have find_elements_by_accessibility_id('some id'): function...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with plain selenium webdriver like so:

```py
driver.find_element("accessibility id", "some id")
```

That is basically all the helper method in the appium client is doing behind the scenes.  It even works directly with WinAppDriver apart from Appium.